# Deploy to azure error - Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions

Tags: c#, azure

I have an app running on azure. I have recently updated it to .NET 7 but the deploy always works fine. Yesterday I deployed the app without changing or adding a dependency and I got this exception.

*System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.AddLogging(IServiceCollection services, Action`1 configure) at*

When I run the project **locally it starts without an error**. I have tried to add the missing dependency but this does not fix the error.
[image]
[image]

I have also checked the wwwroot folder on azure but the dll is there

[image]

What I have tried :

- Add the missing .dll
- Delete .vs, bin and obj folder
- Tried to change the version suggested here  [Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64823766/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-extensions-logging-abstractions)

Is there anything I have missed to change it? Any help is welcome.

Update:

As Harshitha suggest in the comments I have also the following lines to the .csproj and to my webconfig. But it does not help

.csproj

```
    <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="packages\microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions\7.0.0\.signature.p7s" />
    <Content Include="packages\microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions\7.0.0\microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions.7.0.0.nupkg" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="7.0.0" Culture="neutral" PublicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" processorArchitecture="MSIL">
        <HintPath>packages\microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions\7.0.0\lib\net7.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

web.config

```
    <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: This type of issue occurs when there is a conflict with the installed package Version.We need to add the package within the dependent assembly section in `Web.Config` file.

Comment: Add the below section in `Web.config` file.`<dependentAssembly> <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" /> <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" /> </dependentAssembly>`

Comment: @Harshitha I have tried you suggestion but error still persists. Anything else I can do ?

Comment: Need to add hintpath as mentioned in this so thread.It is for another dll but need to add sections same like this.Refer this thread [once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76356099/19648279)

Comment: @Harshitha I have added the lines aso suggested in the link but error still persists. I have checked the dll version in the wwwroot and it is current 6.0.3. When I check my bin/debug folder there is no Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll. How can force the dll build ?

Comment: I have updated my description above with the things I have done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254127/discussion-between-harshitha-and-manuel1234).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have mentioned in the Comments this type of issue arise because of the same package installed with two different versions (Version Conflict).

***Example:***

When you have installed `Serilog.AspNetCore`, the package `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions` is included in the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`.

[image]

> When I check my bin/debug folder there is no Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll.

- As `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions` is under `Serilog.AspNetCore` , it will not be available in the bin folder.
- Initially even Iam unable to find the package in `bin`.
  [image]
- You might have installed the same package again with another version.

> How can force the dll build ?

This can be done in either of the below way:

Either by installing the latest version in VS Local, build and re-deploying the app.

***OR***

By copying the required version directly in `wwwroot` folder (which you have already done and worked for you).